# Trying to draw shapes which are selected from toolbar at the mouse position-HTML5 CANVAS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouselistener

Hey guys i'm trying to create an interactive app whereby users can select the shape they want and then click anywhere on the canvas and the shape appears at that position. I've been able to do it for one shape only so far. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script>

 function initiateCanvasRectangle()
 {
     var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
     ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
         var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
         var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
     });

     ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
         var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;

         ctx.fillRect(mouseX,mouseY,100,50);
    });

 }

 function initiateCanvasCircle()
 {
     var ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
     ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
         var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
         var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
     });

     ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
         var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;

         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
         ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
         ctx.fill();
    });

 }

 function rect(){  //so that the function is triggered only when the user selects the shape
 window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
     initiateCanvasRectangle();
 });
 }

 function drawRect()
 {
     rect();
 }

 function circle(){  //as from here the code is not working
  window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
     initiateCanvasCircle();
 });
 }

 function drawCircle()
 {
    circle();
 }

 </script>

 <style>

 BUTTON.rect {
     padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
     font-family: Arial, Verdana;   
     background-color: white;
     border:2px solid black;
 }


 #tbl {
     border-collapse:collapse;
 }

 </style>
</head>

<body>
<div align="left">
<table border="1" id="tbl" width="1100" height="100">
<div align="right">
<tr><td><button class="circle" onclick="drawCircle(); return true;" style="padding:20px 40px 20px 40px;">Circle</button>
</td>
<td>
<button class="rect" onclick="drawRect(); return true;" style="padding:20px 40px 20px 40px;"></button>
</td></tr>
</div>
</table>
<p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1100" height="400" style="border:solid 1px black;"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click on the button for the rectangle it works fine but i can't seem to draw the circle when i click on its button. Is there any mistake in my codes?
What i created so far is only for trying purposes so please disregard the look of the page.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You never define radius variable used in this line:

```
ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
```

Set it to some value like 50, and it will work.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/8eUT0hRXA40K53Dy0xDl?p=preview

Comment: OMG You're a genius! Was thinking it must be a silly mistake. Thanks.